# MVC Scaffolding not loading data context class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, dbcontext

I've got a web project in VS2013 Ultimate where add scaffolding screen isn't loading the DBContext objects into the window. See the following image. The project has 2 EDMX files that have EF6 generated DBContexts. One of them is within the web application the other is in a separate assembly.

[image]

I can't for the life off me figure out what is going on. I'm about to crack ILSpy and pull the MVC Scaffolding apart to see why it isn't working but I thought I'd ask here first. Just to cut some people off at the pass, I've already done the safe mode / clean & rebuild / restart VS and nothing has changed the behaviour. I have a separate, testing solution that has this working but for some reason this solution is fubar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: build the solution then try

Comment: @Ni3 Thanks for the comment but please read the whole post. You might find sentences such as "Just to cut some people off at the pass, I've already done the safe mode / clean & rebuild / restart VS and nothing has changed the behaviour" important.

Comment: Ok - so it turns out that any data context or model classes that are in a namespace starting with Microsoft.* are hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so it turns out that any data context or model classes that are in a namespace starting with Microsoft.* are hidden. It's a bug that only affects Microsoft internal staff.

Comment: Hi, I got the same problem too and my data context is not started with Microsoft.*  VS2013 CE. Any idea?

Comment: G'day Edwin. My issue was the EF time was filtering out all namespaces that start with Microsoft. What have steps have you taken so far to debug this? Have you restarted VS / rebuild solution etc etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if you have the correct using statement in your Context class.
This works for me:
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
instead of this:
`using System.Data.Entity;`